# Finding where inline styles come from

Tags: jquery, css, inline-styles

I have a problem with a Prestashop page. Whenever I resize the window, my hero element get's a set of inline styles, a width set in pixels and a margin-left. I cannot override this with jQuery since these styles seem to be recalculated and re-added everytime the window changes. Is there something I can do about this?.

The url is: http://paolaq.com/test/es/

Comment: What is hero element?

Comment: Try removing "div_full_width" class. One of your libs set based on this class. Edit: I found code, its in global.js

Comment: use `!important` in css rules to override inline style properties

Comment: Ibrahimyilmaz was correct, that class was the culprit. Thank you. !important didn't work in this case as the class was overriding it all the time.

Comment: `!important` will always work if use specific enough selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your global.js file 621. line:

```
function div_full_width(){
    var $ = jQuery;
    var contn_width = 1170;
    var window_width = $('#index').width();//$(window).width();

    // set container width
    if( window_width >= 1200 ) {
        contn_width = 1170;
    }else if( window_width >= 992 ){
        contn_width = 970;
    }else if( window_width >= 768 ){
        contn_width = 750;
    }else{
        contn_width = window_width;
    }

    $('.div_full_width').each(function(){
        $(this).css({
            //'margin-left': - ($(window).width() - $('#columns').width())/2,
            //'width': $(window).width()
            'margin-left': - (window_width - contn_width)/2,
            'width': window_width
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Yep, that was class causing it, I'll accept this as you took the time to find where it was and all. Thank you.

Comment: Good Answer.. @ibrahimyilmaz